# Possible to use javascript FileSystem in incognito?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filesystems

Trying to get something like this
https://simpl.info/video/offline/
to work in incognito, but the FileSystem API throws security error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileSystem API is [not well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem). I recommend using [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) instead, or use the [localForage](http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/) polyfill library if certain [features](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) of that library are not available in certain browsers. These should be supported in Incognito mode. I quickly tested with Local Storage and that works.

Comment: Exactly what I've been searching for! Bravo